# Left joining table to itself with WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table called '**guests**' with these columns:

- guest_id
- wedding_id
- fname
- lname
- inviter_id

I need to select all the guests from a certain `wedding_id` and left join the actual inviter `fname` and `lname` instead of `inviter_id` (which corresponds with the guest id).

I got this far:

```
SELECT u.fname fname, u.lname lname, r.fname inviter_f, r.lname inviter_l 
FROM guests u LEFT JOIN guests r ON u.inviter_id = r.guest_id
```

The only piece of the puzzle that I'm missing is adding a:

```
where wedding_id=10
```

(to select results only for a specific wedding id).

After edit:
The final query:
**SELECT u.fname fname, u.lname lname, r.fname inviter_f, r.lname inviter_l 
    FROM guests u LEFT JOIN guests r ON u.inviter_id = r.guest_id where u.wedding_id=10**

Now a follow up question:

How do I return empty ' ' values where there is no inviter_id(set as 0), at the current query it returns it as NULL? (inviter_f and inviter_l returns NULL)

Comment: whats happening when you add where u.wedding_id=10 ?

Comment: You probably need to say where u.wedding_id=10 or r.wedding_id=10

Comment: I love you Gayathri!! I tried adding it inside the query instead of just appending it to the end if it. IT WORKS!!! ahhhhhh :)

here is the final query:
SELECT u.fname fname, u.lname lname, r.fname inviter_f, r.lname inviter_l 
    FROM guests u LEFT JOIN guests r ON u.inviter_id = r.guest_id where u.wedding_id=10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT u.fname fname, u.lname lname, r.fname inviter_f, r.lname inviter_l FROM guests u LEFT JOIN guests r ON u.inviter_id = r.guest_id WHERE u.wedding_id = 10
```

Comment: It works! thanks! a follow up question: how do I return empty value '' instead of NULL inviter_f and inviter_l ?
thanks!

Comment: SELECT u.fname fname, u.lname lname, IF(r.fname IS NULL, '', r.fname) inviter_f, IF(r.lname IS NULL, '', r.lname) inviter_l FROM guests u LEFT JOIN guests r ON u.inviter_id = r.guest_id WHERE u.wedding_id = 10

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM guests u LEFT JOIN guests r ON u.inviter_id = r.guest_id and r.wedding_id = u.wedding_id where u.wedding_id = 10;
```

Comment: You can't put `WHERE` before `JOIN`.

Comment: I tried that, it seems that you cant put where anywhere except for the end of the query... but thanks :)